# Backend Error on insertAll requests

Tags: google-bigquery

50% of our data is suddenly failing to post to Bigquery via the insertAll request.  Started happening on Tuesday July 7th around 6am central time.  Google Cloud Status page reports no outage.  No code changes or service restarts had occurred on our side.

We have whittled our processing down to a single connection and single record at a time.  The request length is very small.  We have retry logic with backoff, no number of retries helps.  It could be related to the post body itself but everything appears to be encoded properly as UTF8.  We process data sequentially so this has been a major outage for the past 2 days.

**The very interesting part is if I strip out non US-ASCII characters from the json, there is no failures.**

I have turned on CONFIG level logging on the HttpTransport class to see the request and response info.  I have a single request/response log including our own stacktrace.

https://gist.github.com/lukeforehand/37528fd680a8facdd621

I would love to get some eyes on this from the server side, we simply see "backend error".

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Backend error` means something is going on with the infrastructure and app on the nodes your project is internally assigned. You cannot fix or improve this, only BQ team engineers can fix the issue.

If the problem doesn't go away after retries, you need to reach out to

- your assigned BigQuery engineer
- paid support on https://cloud.google.com/support/
- file a bug report, report a performance issue, feature request on https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: Thanks, we have contacted paid support over 24 hours ago.

Comment: @lukeforehand As pentium10 is pointing out, you needed to notify the backend team, which I see from your message you did. I dug around and found what I think is your current ticket and I can see there's been a lot of movement on it (if I found the right ticket). At this point you will have to wait for resolution from the support team

Comment: Thanks Patrice.  We are definitely in communication with the backend team.  The issue is not yet resolved but I feel like they are working diligently on the issue.

Comment: @lukeforehand Glad to hear :) I kept your issue open to check it when I had a chance today, Happy to know that it works now. Have fun on the platform, enjoy the upcoming weekend ^^